# Printing what is inside a modal

Tags: html, css, angularjs, bootstrap-modal, angularjs-ng-click

I have a modal where I want to print the full contents of it.  I don't want anything else printed aside what is within the modal.

Here I created the button within the modal:

```
This should not be printed...
    <button id="btnPrint">Print (this btn should not be printed!)</button>

    <hr />

    <div id="printThis">
        This should BE printed!
    </div>

    <div id="printThisToo">
        This should BE printed, too!
    </div>
```

I have some text next to the button, but this text should not show when you click the button to preview the print view.

Here I wrote some js to show what content should be printed:

```
document.getElementById("btnPrint").onclick = function() {
    printElement(document.getElementById("printThis"));
    printElement(document.getElementById("printThisToo"), true, "<hr />");
    window.print();
}

function printElement(elem, append, delimiter) {
    var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);

    var $printSection = document.getElementById("printSection");

    if (!$printSection) {
        var $printSection = document.createElement("div");
        $printSection.id = "printSection";
        document.body.appendChild($printSection);
    }

    if (append !== true) {
        $printSection.innerHTML = "";
    }

    else if (append === true) {
        if (typeof(delimiter) === "string") {
            $printSection.innerHTML += delimiter;
        }
        else if (typeof(delimiter) === "object") {
            $printSection.appendChlid(delimiter);
        }
    }

    $printSection.appendChild(domClone);
}
```

Finally, I wrote some css:

```
@media screen {
  #printSection {
      display: none;
  }
}

@media print {

    body {
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: 500;
        color: #101010;
        background: #f6f5fa;
        visibility:hidden;
    }
  #printSection, #printSection {
    visibility:visible;
  }
  #printSection {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
  }

}
```

When I click the button in the modal, nothing happens and no errors appear in the console.  Not sure what the issue is.  Any help would be much appreciated.

---

**UPDATED CODE:**

(HTML)

```
    <div>
        This should not be printed...
        <button ng-click="printPreview()">Print (this btn should not be printed!)</button>
    </div>

    <hr />

    <div id="printThis">
        This should BE printed!
    </div>
```

(JS)

```
var app = angular.module('dmdesktop');

app.controller('PrintViewCtrl', rollUpCtrl);
rollUpCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', '$uibModal','headersvc','locFiltersvc']
function rollUpCtrl($scope, $rootScope, $http, $uibModal, headersvc, locFiltersvc) {

    $scope.printPreview = function() {
        printElement(document.getElementById("printThis"));
    }

    function printElement(elem) {
        alert ("printing!");
        var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);

        var $printSection = document.getElementById("printSection");

        if (!$printSection) {
            var $printSection = document.createElement("div");
            $printSection.id = "printSection";
            document.body.appendChild($printSection);
        }

        $printSection.innerHTML = "";
        $printSection.appendChild(domClone);
        window.print();
    }
}
```

(CSS)

same as before

Comment: `visibility: visible` won't override `display:none`. Use `display:block` in your print style.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan  I was able to get a print preview of the modal content, but now I have a weird issue.  In the JS, if I write in an alert in the printElement function (shown above in the updated code), it will show the message of "this should BE printed!"  If I do not have the alert in the function the print preview will just be blank with no message shown.  It is very inconsistent for some reason.  Maybe the alert allows enough time for the message to show and without the message it is not given enough time to go through the code.  Any suggestions?

Comment: put the `window.print()` in a `$scope.$evalAsync(function () { ... });` or a `$timeout(function () { ... });` construct. It's probably printing before the digest cycle has completed.

Comment: Perfect.  Using a $scope.$evalAsync function with window.print(); worked.  Thank you for your time to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the updated code and window.print inside a evalAsync function allows you to print the content inside a modal

```
 $scope.$evalAsync(function () {
            window.print();
        });
```